# Вывод лога на форме в C# + многопоток

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня стоит такая задача - вывод лог действий на форму. Я решил использовать listBox, так как там можно легко регулировать кол-во строк отображаемых в компоненте. Работа происходит в многопотоке (потоков много) ибо идет работа с сетью.
Я написал такой код

```
if (!_useLogger)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (_lockLog)
        {
            Action actionLog = () =>
            {
                TxtLoggerBox.Items
                .Add($"{Logger.GetLogString(message)}");
                if (TxtLoggerBox.Items.Count > 17)
                {
                    TxtLoggerBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            };
            if (TxtLoggerBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                TxtLoggerBox.Invoke(actionLog);
            }
            else
            {
                actionLog();
            }

            actionLog = null;
        }
```

И меня интересует такой вопрос, как я могу выводит логи на форму в многопотоке и при этом не нагружать процессор и оперативную память. Плюс интересует будет ли утечка памяти в таком варианте как я написал.

Comment: Метод `Logger.GetLogString` тяжёлый или лёгкий? Если первое, то хорошо бы его вынести наружу, чтобы он не выполнялся в GUI-потоке. Но при этом он должен быть потокобезопасным. Если это не так, то оставляем как есть.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Легкий, он просто возвращает строку в нужном формате

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утечки быть не должно. lock (_lockLog), если я не ошибаюсь не обязателен, ибо TxtLoggerBox.Invoke сам по себе потокобезопасен. Странно, что вы используете проверку InvokeRequired для достаточно тяжёлого элемента listBox. Проверку InvokeRequired есть смысл использовать только если в лог летят данные отовсюду (в том числе из потока GUI), а не только из сети.
Обязательно нужно использовать проверку IsDisposed, т.к. при закрытии формы ещё могут приходить данные и вызываться функция записи в лог, в итоге программа будет крашиться при закрытии окна с listBox.
Ещё вы каждый раз пересоздаёте actionLog, и зачем-то удаляете его. А это очень дорогое удовольствие. Лучше вынесите функцию actionLog наружу, ещё можно сделать функцию статической, но тогда и заводить статическую ссылку на listbox и проверять на null, т.е. гемора не мало.

Но если вам нужен listbox, то можно так:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

BindingList<string> log = new BindingList<string>(); //список, который умеет сам стрелять событиями
listbox.DataSource = log; //аттачим как источник данных
bool _useLogger = true;
uint limit = 17;

public void addToLog(string s)
{
    if (!_useLogger) return;
    if (log.Count > limit)
    {
        log.RaiseListChangedEvents = false; //блокируем вызов события дабы избежать двойной отрисовки
        log.RemoveAt(0);
        log.RaiseListChangedEvents = true; //разблокируем
    }
    log.Add(s);
}
```

При закрытии формы, листбокс сам диспозится и отключает событие от BindingList, в итоге данные могут писаться и дальше в лог, функция будет работать, но всё будет безопасно и listbox не выдаст никаких ошибок.

Comment: _Проверку InvokeRequired есть смысл использовать только если в лог летят данные отовсюду_ - именно так: у автора используется многопоток.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вызовы из потоков у него только со стороны потоков, общающихся с сетью (если судить по его примеру кода), из потока формы вызовов нет, следовательно TxtLoggerBox.Invoke - нужен всегда, поэтому проверка InvokeRequired излишняя.

Comment: Я думал, вы вообще от `Invoke` предлагаете отказаться. Не так понял.

Answer (score 1):

у Вас всё сделано правильно в том смысле, что в многоптосном приложении всё должно выводиться.

Но есть проблема: при возрастании кол-ва инфомации на экране будет расти и возрастание потребления CPU. Потму что при каждом рефреше листбокса надо всё больше айтемов в нём рефрешить.

Утечки памяти, конечно же, не будет - потому что откуда она возьмётся, код то managed и никаких хитрых объектов с зависимостями не создаётся.

Можно сделать вот что:

1. Перейти на простой multiline textbox
2. Использовать то, что называется "кольцевой буфер": Вы выводите на экран, предположим, последние 50 строк. Остальное - уходит в Нирвану. Ну, то есть, в текстовый файл. Тогда кол-во отображаемый айтемов - фиксировано, и потребление CPU будет ограничено перерисовкой этих 50 строк.
3. Можно вообще выводить лог в текстовый файл, и смотреть его внешней програмомой, например, [LogExpert](https://github.com/zarunbal/LogExpert/)

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Но вот правильный ли у меня ход мыслей. Я создаю стрингбилдер, фиксирую его максимальную вместимость. Отдельный метод будет следить, если буфер заполняется, он выводит все на экран и очищает его (предварительно закинул в "нирвану")

Comment: Кажется понял, пойду читать про кольцевой буфер) то что выше, фигню сморозил

Comment: Ну, в общем, тут идея такая: есть массив строк, и этот массив - фиксировоанной длинны. Есть указатель. Он бегает по массиву "по кругу". На каждом шаге приходится стринг билдером пробежаться по всем элементам массива и построить представление "последних 50 записей". И вывести их в TextBox. Работа для процессора есть на кадждом шаге, но она ограничена.

Comment: Количество айтемов не растёт бесконечно. `if (...Items.Count > 17) ...Items.RemoveAt(0)`. Фактически уже реализован кольцевой буфер.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - точно, спасибо за подсказку!